# Why do we need a $Bx$ term for partial fractions with irreducible quadratic factors?

Tags: partial-fractions

Why is there Bx+c term when we try to split partial fraction with irreducible quadratic?

Eg:

$$\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$$

I think that splitting partial fraction is intuition when we directly put it as $\frac{A}{linear factor}$
but I don't understand why we have to introduce a $Bx$ term for quadratic factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instructive to see what happens if you omit it. Suppose we had
$$
\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2+1}
$$Cross multiplying, we get
$$
1 = A (x^2+1) + B(x)
$$Matching the constant terms, we see $A=1$; matching the quadratic terms, we see $A=0$. This is a contradiction, so our decomposition is invalid. The need for a linear term is to balance the degree of the quadratic in the denominator.

If you were working over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, you could split $x^2+1$ completely:
$$
\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} = \frac{1}{x(x+i)(x-i)} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{\beta}{x+i}+\frac{\gamma}{x-i}
$$Combining the last two terms gives
$$
\frac{\beta}{x+i}+\frac{\gamma}{x-i} = \frac{\beta(x-i)+\gamma(x+i)}{x^2+1} = \frac{B x + C}{x^2+1}
$$

Comment: You should get on the LHS $x$ and not $1$, when you cross multiply

Comment: Umm so how would one know when to assume of the form Ax+B ?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz working over $\mathbb{R}$, whenever you have an irreducible quadratic. This happens when the discriminant [in $ax^2+bx+c$, the quantity $b^2-4ac$] is less than $0$.

Comment: Would we assume Ax+B if the original denominator was of the form (dx^2+cx+f)^2?

Comment: No; consider $(x^2-1)^2$, which we could factor as $(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$. The issue here is that you need multiple factors to account for the multiplicity; being irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ is a different condition.

Comment: I don't consider this answer satisfactory. It just goes and says that if you don't do this then you get the wrong answer... which doesn't shed insight onto the 'why?' of things.

Comment: That's a fair critique. Do you buy the second bit about splitting completely over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: that's a good idea actually I didn't understand it when I first read it.  I think both answers posted now have it's own insight in themselves. I'll wait and see if there is some other idea also left

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}=x\cdot\frac{1}{x^2(x^2+1)}=x\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}.$$

Also
$$ A = \lim_{x\to 0} x f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2+1} = 1$$
so $Bx+C$ can be found by simplifying $f(x)-\frac{1}{x}$.